# Supply a literal array to a Polar expression

Tags: python, python-polars

How can I define a literal array in a Polars expression? For example, if I wanted to filter if an expression was true and a given value in a mask was true.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]))
mask = [True, True, False, False, True, True]

df.filter(pl.col('x') % 2 == 0 & pl.lit(mask))
# could not convert value [True, True, False, False, True, True] as a Literal
```

For this particular example, I could use `[]` indexing on the data frame and then do the filter, but for more complicated expressions, it would be easier if I could insert the array into the expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
df.filter((pl.col("x") % 2 == 0) & pl.Series(mask))
```

Note the added parentheses.  The `(pl.col("x") % 2 == 0)` produces a Series of boolean, which is then bit-anded row-wise with the `pl.Series(mask)`.

Using a Series also allows you to set the data type of the values, which can come in handy.

The documentation of the [Series constructor](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Series.html#polars.Series) explains more.

Comment: So the main point (besides adding parentheses) was to use `pl.Series`, not `pl.lit`?

Comment: Correct.  `pl.lit` is for broadcasting a single value to a column.  `pl.Series` allows you to specify the array of contents for the column.  In some sense, `pl.lit(1)` == `pl.Series([1,1,1,1,1,....])`

Comment: Interestingly, using a `Series` alone fails; it must be part of a larger expression.